# Windows CMD to find all .py files in subfolders exluding one

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd

I had a command to search for all .py files end execute pep8 check on every file:

```
FOR /R %%i IN (*.py) DO pep8 %%i
```

Now, I need to execute the same command on all .py files, except those located in "migrations" directory

I tried everyting i found and nothing helps.
I tried this but it still searches in migrations directories:

```
set "logDirectory=C:\workspace"  
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d/b/s "%logDirectory%"^|findstr /riv "^.*[\\][^\\]*migrations[^\\]*$"') do pep8 %%a
```

Running Windows.

Comment: Is there just one "migrations" directory or many? Is its (their) location fixed?

Comment: There are many directories, and they can be located anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `FINDSTR` -- that command is useful to filter files based on their *contents*. Use `FIND` instead:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b/s "%logDirectory%\*.py" ^| find /v /i "\migrations\"') do pep8 %%a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option using for /r

```
@echo off
FOR /R %%i IN (*.py) DO (echo "%%i" |find /i "\migrations\">nul) || pep8 "%%i"
```